# Force `importrange()' to update data

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I'm using the `importrange()` formula inside of Google Sheets to import a bunch of data from multiple spreadsheets into one sheet. On this one sheet I'm using circa 20 `importrange()` formula's each importing circa 250 cells.

The problem is if I change any of the data in the original source sheets the import sheet takes hours to update. Any idea why this would be and what I can do to force an update

Answer (score -1):

- include **`NOW`** in your formula or sheet and enable recalculation in settings:

  [image: 0]